# Anticipating Common Questions and Text Variation

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to build out a test case for a chat bot but am trying to populate the different inputs that the user may ask.. Example, answers for what the status of a project is:

What's the status of X?
What's the status of X
what is X's status?
wat is the status on this?
Can you tell me the status of X?

Is there any sort of library or easier way to identify these? The output of this is going to Power Virtual Agents, so I can't use fuzzy matching to condense it into a single question

Comment: You may be interested in this: https://www.nltk.org/

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem though... From my understanding, NLTK can view that all of these statements are similar, but it can't go backwards (e.g. generate different combinations)